# How to print True or False if a is bigger than b

Tags: r

I have data in R and I want print True if DST is bigger than AriT in another column.
Here is the part of data that I've got

```
AriT   DST
1516   1450
1150   1518
1502   1519 
1343   1210
```

Below query is what I've got so far but some how they all print TRUE.

```
outpatient_data["check"] <- if(any(outpatient_data$AriT<outpatient_data$DST)) {
    "TRUE"
} else {
   "FALSE"
}
```

can some one please help me what I've done wrong?

Comment: Just do `with(outpatient_data, Arit < DST)`  No need for `if/else`  as the logical operation output as TRUE/FALSE

Answer (score 2):

I am going to step-by-step explaining what is going on here.

First, let's recreate your example data frame.

```
outpatient_data <- read.table(text = "AriT   DST
1516   1450
1150   1518
1502   1519 
1343   1210",
                              header = TRUE, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```

Now let's type `outpatient_data$AriT < outpatient_data$DST` in the console. You will see R print the following.

```
outpatient_data$AriT < outpatient_data$DST
# [1] FALSE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE
```

This is a logical vector with `TRUE` or `FALSE`. As akrun suggested in the comment, at this point, it has been ready for you to assign this vector to create your new column.

Now let's put the above line inside the `any` function.

```
any(outpatient_data$AriT<outpatient_data$DST)
# [1] TRUE
```

The output is just one element, `TRUE` or `FALSE`. This is what the `any` function does. It evaluates a vector to see if any elements are `TRUE`. Since the output from `outpatient_data$AriT<outpatient_data$DST` is `FALSE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE`, the output is `TRUE`.

Finally, let's look at the entire code.

```
outpatient_data["check"] <- if(any(outpatient_data$AriT<outpatient_data$DST)) {
  "TRUE"
} else {
  "FALSE"
}
```

Because the content inside the `if` condition is `any(outpatient_data$AriT<outpatient_data$DST)`, which is `TRUE`, this `if-else` statement would always go to the first chunck, which returns character `"TRUE"`. This character is then assigned to the new column `"check"`. Furthermore, because the length of this character is one, while the row number of your data frame is more than one, the character would be recycled. This is why you will get a column all with the character `"TRUE"`.

One final note. In R, `TRUE` or `FALSE` are reserved words for logical condition. In your code, you tried to assign character `"TRUE"` or `"FALSE"`. This is very confusing not only for you, but also for other readers. Please avoid this happens unless you really need a character `"TRUE"` or `"FALSE"`.

Comment: Thanks! It really helped! Can I ask you one more question? If I want to delete the values in AriT which is greater than DST(saying False in Check column). what kind of query do I need to use?

Comment: https://www.statmethods.net/management/subset.html   This could be helpful.

Comment: > subset(outpatient_data$AriT, outpatient_data$check!= "TRUE") I use this query to delete variables in AriT and some how they are not disappearing....

Comment: As I mentioned in my post, ''TRUE" is a character, so `outpatient_data$check!= "TRUE"` does not make sense to me. `!outpatient_data$check` makes more sense to me if you are working on logical condition.

Comment: It still stay same if I use !outpatient_data$check. Do I need to assign them as NULL if I want to delete the variable which is FALSE in check column?

Comment: `subset(outpatient_data, !outpatient_data$check)` works for me. Please make sure the content in the `check` column is in logical condition.

Answer (score 1):

R comes with built-in vectorisation, which means a lot of operations naturally apply to each element of a vector. So you can directly use `<` to compare `AriT` and `DST` and it will return a vector of `TRUE` and `FALSE`.

```r
outpatient_data <- data.frame(
  AriT = c(1516, 1150, 1502, 1343),
  DST = c(1450, 1518, 1519, 1210)
)

outpatient_data["check"] <- outpatient_data$AriT < outpatient_data$DST
outpatient_data
#>   AriT  DST check
#> 1 1516 1450 FALSE
#> 2 1150 1518  TRUE
#> 3 1502 1519  TRUE
#> 4 1343 1210 FALSE
```

Your code is returning all `TRUE` because you used `any`, which takes a vector as input and returns `TRUE` if **any** of the values are true. It also will recycle the value to fill the whole length of the data frame, which is why it produces all `TRUE` instead of just one as below.

```r
any(outpatient_data$check)
#> [1] TRUE
```

Created on 2018-08-23 by the [reprex package](http://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.2.0).